# Can't access my own followers on instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

So i'm trying to access my own followers through the API. I set the scope to include followers_list. However when I call https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=sometokenhere 
I receive code 200 and no data. My application is in sandbox mode. Any reason why I can't access my own followers/following?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sandbox mode you will only get response for posts and users that are in your sandbox user list.

So add one of the users u follow to sandbox, then only that user will be in API response, once your app is reviewed, approved and live, all the users will show up in API response.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/